# Laravel php artisan -mcr flag error when accessing another computer on a wifi network

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

When I try to use `php artisan make:model CourseCategory -mcr` command, I get the following error

[image]

I have tried using:

- PHP version below 7.2
- Window null issue mentioned

**I use PHP 7.3, Laravel 5.8 on windows 10**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the sample code as part of the text (formated)

Comment: `artisan` command doesn't have `--mcr` flag. You need to explain better what are you doing.

Comment: @Stalinko i have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

That is a windows OS problem check this link here:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8426

Someone wrote he did this to solve it:

```
I solved it by moving the project out of the One Drive Directory.
```

Comment: I'm not using `One Drive Directory`  @lewis4u